# Invalid character in identifier (Python3)

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium, automated-tests

I don't understand where the invalid character is, it points at the end of the code.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys


def page_is_loaded(driver):
   return driver.find_element_by_tag_name("body") != None

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.adidas.co.uk/on/demandware.store/Sites-adidas-GB-Site/en_GB/MyAccount-Register")
year = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH,'//spa‌​n[@data-val="1990"]'‌​)))
driver.execute_script('arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);', year)
                                                                            ^
SyntaxError: invalid character in identifier
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.  Error messages often flag something on a syntactically recent line; we need enough code to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Sorry about that.

Comment: there seems to be some odd characters at the end of `"1990"]'‌​)))` in the parentheses. It shows up in the interpreter as `"]'\U+200C​)))`. Try replacing them with this, `')))`, copy and paste. At least that cleared the error for me.

Comment: Kinda worked but the drop down isnt scrolling down.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As was said, there is a hidden symbol in `"1990"]'`. This sometimes happened when you copy code from `StackOverflow`. You just need to retype this part again.

If you need to scroll down to target option (`1990`), use

```
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
driver.get("https://www.adidas.co.uk/on/demandware.store/Sites-adidas-GB-Site/en_GB/MyAccount-Register")
driver.switch_to_frame(driver.find_element_by_xpath('//iframe[@class="sso-iframe"]'))
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,'//a[.="YY"]'))).click()
year = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,'//li[span[@data-val="1990"]]' )))
year.location_once_scrolled_into_view
time.sleep(1)
year.click()
```